# Network Failure while download Using PHP Script

Tags: php, file, download

I am getting network failure message in chrome but working on other browser using php download script.

I have below headers set to download.

```
cache-control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
content-disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv"
content-length: 388436
content-type: application/octet-stream
date: Thu, 19 Jul 2018 13:41:02 GMT
expires: Wed, 19 Jul 2017 13:40:59 GMT
last-modified: Thu, 19 Jul 2018 13:41:02 GMT
pragma: public
server: nginx
set-cookie: admin=p5t1vd4e4u3j9g6gto5h046ki0; path=/admin; domain=xyz.com; secure; HttpOnly
status: 200
x-powered-by: PHP/7.0.29
```

I am getting error in chrome version 67.3396.99

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Failed - Network error after downloading file in chrome download section.